# Не видит считыватель смарт карт при подключении через USB-COM конвертер

Tags: c#, serial, com-порт

Вопрос простой - есть считыватель СБСК 03 Rosan (Serial + USB питание), не могу с ним работать. Подключение через USB-COM конвертер (точно рабочий Profilic pl2303), ком порт в системе есть. Не получаю никаких данных с порта, спец прога от Profilic распознает свое оборудование. Подключенный по такой схеме ридер не вижу - ни через putty, ни программными способами C#, ни ОС Windows 8 x64, так же испробовано некоторое количество софта для работы и прослушивания COM порта, все безрезультатно. Уже неделю воюю, есть у кого-нибудь опыт работы с такими устройствами?

Comment: Внутри у считывателя(в первом приближении) - NXP MFRC531, ADM232AASRW, AT891xx и антена.

Comment: Какие данные хочешь получить с ридера? Какие карты пытаешься считать? Используешь ли ключевую карту?